# simple tutorial for creating restaurant views with Views and CCK

Tags: drupal

I wonder if there are simple tutorials out there teaching you how to create a restaurant page with Views and CCK.

I cant understand when people just say: use CCK and Views.

Maybe there is an easy-to-follow-tutorial somewhere on this topic?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely lots of great tutorials out there, one of my favorites Drupal sites for tutorials is GotDrupal.com, here is a good beginning Views tutorial (http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-tutorial) and a good beginning CCK tutorial (http://gotdrupal.com/videos/understanding-drupal-content-types-cck). If you are willing to fork out some cash, Lullabot has a some [great videos as well](http://store.lullabot.com/products/cck-views-bundle)